# how i can print the result in one line and with space for each character

Tags: python, dictionary, binary, converters

```
binary = {
    "a": "01100001",
    "b": "01100010",
    "c": "01100011",
    "d": "01100100",
    "e": "01100101",
    "f": "01100110",
    "g": "01100111",
    "h": "01101000",
    "i": "01101001",
    "j": "01101010",
    "k": "01101011",
    "l": "01101100",
    "m": "01101101",
    "n": "01101110",
    "o": "01101111",
    "p": "01110000",
    "q": "01110001",
    "r": "01110010",
    "s": "01110011",
    "t": "01110100",
    "u": "01110101",
    "v": "01110110",
    "w": "01110111",
    "x": "01111000",
    "y": "01111001",
    "z": "01111010"
}

while True:
    converter = input("Convert decimal to binary: ")
    for i in converter:
        print(binary.get(i))
```

i was expecting the output be like this:
ex:

```
input = hello 
output = 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is.  What output did you **actually get**, and how was it **different** than what you expected?

Comment: Also, "Convert decimal to binary" does not seem to be an actual good description, since the user is entering _letters_, not _decimal numbers_.

Comment: Yes true, but i am just trying to convert from decimal to binary only, thank you for your answer.
For your question, i get it right but what is to get the binary numbers to be in one row and separate from each other.

Answer (score 1):

You could control what is added at the end of a printed string, by providing the `end` parameter.

```py
while True:
    converter = input("Convert decimal to binary: ")
    for i in converter:
        print(binary.get(i), end=" ") # add a space after the printed binary number
    print() # this prints a new line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sep` argument to specify a separator for the `print` function while mapping characters from the input to the `binary.get` method:

```
while True:
    converter = input("Convert decimal to binary: ")
    print(*map(binary.get, converter), sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
binary = { "a": "01100001", "b": "01100010", "c": "01100011", "d": "01100100", "e": "01100101", "f": "01100110", "g": "01100111", "h": "01101000", "i": "01101001", "j": "01101010", "k": "01101011", "l": "01101100", "m": "01101101", "n": "01101110", "o": "01101111", "p": "01110000", "q": "01110001", "r": "01110010", "s": "01110011", "t": "01110100", "u": "01110101", "v": "01110110", "w": "01110111", "x": "01111000", "y": "01111001", "z": "01111010" }

word = []

while True:

    converter = input("Convert decimal to binary: ")

    for i in converter:

        word.append(binary.get(i))

    print(word)

    word = []
```

This would print your word in a list and clear the list every time you put in a new word.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct you just have to set the end parameter to " " in your print statement, as by default it is set to \n

```
print(binary.get(i), end=" ")    #sets end parameter to a " "space gap
```